# CodeIgniter : Undefined variable

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i have this problem

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: title
>
> Filename: views/content_home.php
>
> Line Number: 15

and

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: text1
>
> Filename: views/content_home.php
>
> Line Number: 16

here my view:

```
<div id="content">
<?php


    foreach($results as $row){
            $title = $row->title;
            $text1 = $row->text1;
            $text2 = $row->text2;
            $text3 = $row->text3;
            $text4 = $row->text4;
    }

    ?>
    <div id="leftHome">
            <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
            <p> <?php echo $text1; ?> </p>
            <p><?php echo $text2; ?></p>        
    </div>
    <div id="rightHome">
            <h1><?php echo $text3; ?></h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>site/food"><?php echo $text4; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

here my controller :

```
public function home(){
    $this->load->model("model_get");
    $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("home");  
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_home", $data);
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }
```

and here my model

```
<?php

class Model_get extends CI_Model{
    function getData($page){
        $query = $this->db->get_where("pageData", array("title" =>$page));
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

all text1 - text4 is undefined too. im new to codeigniter, i try anything but still cant find the problem. please help me with this.

Comment: where is this `title` and `text1` coming from? show HTML...

Comment: For one thing, your #leftHome and #rightHome div's should be _inside_ the foreach loop...

Comment: @noobeditor : title and text1 is from my database..

Comment: @mudshark : i try that, thats make another error :(

Comment: Basic debugging. If you dont have xdebug installed, then change your controller  function temporarily to: `public function home(){
    $this->load->model("model_get");
    $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("home"); var_dump($data["results"]);}` and show what you get

Comment: @user574632 : well, i got this 
array(0) { }

Comment: @pricilia OK, well that shows that you are not getting any results back from the database, so something is wrong with your model

Comment: @user574632 really? can you see what is wrong with my model?

Comment: @user574632 i just following tutorial from youtube, that just the same model. idk whats wrong with that.

Comment: @pricilia Not without seeing your database. Check that the database table and column names are correct, and that you actually have data in the table

Comment: @user574632 this is my database SS, http://i1220.photobucket.com/albums/dd442/AndreasMangunsong/db_zpsd8f31ecc.png

Comment: @pricilia Ok, well looks like you have a typo in your model, `get_where("pageData"` should be `get_where("pagedata"` - notice lowercase `d` in `pagedata`

Comment: @user574632 i notice that too, but still got array(0) { }

Comment: @pricilia Also, your query is looking for a page with the title of `home` yet i dont see a page with that title in your database. Either change the data in the database so one of the rows has a title of `home` or change the title in the controller, eg `$data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("home");` becomes `$data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("Hi Gooders");`

Comment: does your `foreach` works good? and do you want the `title` and `text1` from `results` or they are different from that array?

Comment: @user574632 wow its work. ty men. you made my day.hope theres more people like you, again tx for helping me.

Comment: :) glad it worked.. all the best

Answer (score 0):

use the code for your model->

```
class Model_get extends CI_Model{
    function getData($page){
        $this->db->select('title, text1, text2, text3, text4');
        $query = $this->db->get_where("pageData", array("title" =>$page));
        //print_r($query->result());
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

and then **print_r($results)** into your view file at very first and see is the data is coming from your database for your **'title' and 'text1'** or not.